# Custom printf cannot print Nothing

Tags: haskell, printf

I implemented custom `PrintArg` instance for `Maybe`:

```
import Text.Printf

instance PrintfArg a => PrintfArg (Maybe a) where
    formatArg Nothing f str = formatArg "Nothing" f str
    formatArg (Just x) f@(FieldFormat Nothing _ _ _ _ _ _) str = "Just " ++ formatArg x f str
    formatArg (Just x) f@(FieldFormat (Just w) _ Nothing _ _ _ _) str = let
        str' = formatArg x (f {fmtWidth = Nothing}) ""
        in replicate (max 0 (w - 5 - length str')) ' ' ++ "Just " ++ str' ++ str
    formatArg (Just x) f@(FieldFormat (Just w) _ (Just _) _ _ _ _) str = "Just " ++ formatArg x (f {fmtWidth = Just (w-5)}) str
```

It prints `Just` values well:

```
*Main> printf "%10d\n" (Just 2)
    Just 2
*Main> printf "%-10d\n" (Just 2)
Just 2    
*Main> printf "%+10d\n" (Just 2)
   Just +2
*Main> printf "% 10d\n" (Just 2)
   Just  2
*Main> printf "%010d\n" (Just 2)
Just 00002
```

But due to the ambiguous type, it cannot print `Nothing`:

```
*Main> printf "%v\n" Nothing

<interactive>:24:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (PrintfArg a0) arising from a use of ‘printf’
      from the context: PrintfType t
        bound by the inferred type of it :: PrintfType t => t
        at <interactive>:24:1-21
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] PrintfArg Integer -- Defined in ‘Text.Printf’
        instance [safe] PrintfArg a => PrintfArg (Maybe a)
          -- Defined at Test.hs:3:10
        instance [safe] PrintfArg Char -- Defined in ‘Text.Printf’
        ...plus five others
        ...plus 9 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: printf "%v\n" Nothing
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = printf "%v\n" Nothing
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You specify the type: `printf "%v\n" (Nothing :: Maybe Int)`

Comment: This is generally considered a non-issue. E.g. `[] == []` doesn't work either. In any real usage, you won't be directly using `Nothing` as an argument, and so it will work.

Comment: @HTNW “non-issue” is perhaps an exaggeration. There's a reason why Haskell has a defaulting mechanism. Especially in the REPL it would be really tedious having to always specify the type of e.g. number you want to use. It _is_ a bit of a pity that defaulting doesn't really scale to modern Haskell, especially it's little use when advanced type system features are involved.

Comment: I would also suggest to start with `:t Nothing` in ghci. It will print `Nothing :: Maybe a`, meaning type of expression `Nothing` is `Maybe a`. What is the `a` there? No idea for me, as well as no idea for compiler. `a` can be inferred depending on the context, but expression `printf "%v\n" Nothing` gives no enough information to get what `a` is. You have to specify it manually.